# How to send ALT Codes from STM32F103 USB Device Application?

Tags: c, usb, stm32, stm32f1, usb-hid

I have modified the STM32F1 USB HID Device Example generated by STM32CubMX from Mouse to a Keyboard and I am able to send characters to the host by sending the scan codes in the USB Reports.

Now I want some special characters to be sent from the keyboard on the press of a specific button.

They way I see it is to send the scan codes for the keys that comprise the Unicode for the character.

For Example to send a smiley with Unicode U+1F601 (Decimal 128513) to a windows machine I will have to send scan codes for 1,2,8,5,1,3. What I don't understand is how to send this with the ALT Key modifier ?

All the scan codes should be sent in a single report with the ALT Modifier set or in different reports ?

I have a Ubuntu machine and sending CTRL+SHIFT+u in the report then the scan codes followed by an Enter key works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you send the ALT key modifier first and then the scan codes of the keys. That should work just fine. You need to keep in mind the key-down and key-up event so when you don't need the ALT modification you need to send the key-up.

Comment: Comments should not be used to post answers in any case.  This appears to be an answer, so _not posting as a comment_ is exactly the right thing to do.  Including discussion of your SO privileges is however irrelevant.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I just did not have the feeling that my answer was researched in detail, because I remembered it from the top of my head.